# How to solve error by Git when I push origin master?

Tags: git, gitlab

When I try to push to my remote GitLab, I become this error:

```
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 20, done.
Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 1.84 KiB | 269.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 20 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: GitLab:
remote: A default branch (e.g. main) does not yet exist for sandbox/**
remote: Ask a project Owner or Maintainer to create a default branch:
remote:
remote:   https://gitlab**
remote:
To https://gitlab**
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab**
```

I tried to put a new SSH

Comment: Have you not tried anything? Like googling the error?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to guess by reading your post.

Your account on Gitlab may not have been configured to accept pushes onto master branch by you.

Please check you repository settings:

[image: Repository settings]